Android build says: library "libm.so.6" not found
I'm trying to cross compile a dlang vulkan app that I'm trying to deploy to Android.
I run on an Ubuntu desktop and the app compiles fine when I run it as a standalone dlang app.
For deploying as an Android app, I can compile it as a library which I then reference in my Android app. I then copy the libmain.so file to my Android project in Android Studio, fire up the emulator and build and run.
I keep coming up with the above error library "libm.so.6" not found when the app tries to run in the emulator.
As per the other (rare) posts I found while googling, I've added -lm to the project at multiple places, but it doesn't change the result.
I'm running

Android API 31
ndk 27.0.11718104
ldc2 1.38.0-git-4260031 (DMD v2.108.1, LLVM 16.0.6)
x86_64-linux-android31-clang
Android Studio 2022.3.1
Ubuntu 24.04 LTS

Edit001: Following up @charles input, running ldd app/src/main/jniLibs/x86_64/libmain.so gives me
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc955aa000)
        libgtk3-nocsd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0 (0x00007b61dd748000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007b61dd65f000)
   ...
     libdruntime-ldc-shared.so.108 => /home/brian/Documents/Programming/d/install-ldc/lib/libdruntime-ldc-shared.so.108 (0x00007b61dca9d000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007b61dca70000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007b61dc200000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007b61dd76d000)
        libXau.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007b61dd574000)
...

So I added the ndk packaged library location to my ldc2.conf file
"x86_64-linux-android":
{
    switches = [
        "-defaultlib=phobos2-ldc,druntime-ldc",
        "-link-defaultlib-shared=false",
        "-gcc=/home/infinityplusb/Android/Sdk/ndk/27.0.11718014/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/x86_64-linux-android31-clang",
        "-linker=/home/infinityplusb/Android/Sdk/ndk/27.0.11718014/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/ld.lld",
    ];
    lib-dirs = [
       "/home/infinityplusb/Android/Sdk/ndk/27.0.11718014/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-android/31",
        "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu",
        "/home/infinityplusb/Documents/Programming/android/ldc2-1.38.0-linux-x86_64/lib",
        "/home/infinityplusb/Documents/Programming/ffmpeg/ffmpeg-kit/prebuilt/android-x86_64/ffmpeg/lib",
        "%%ldcbinarypath%%/../lib-aarch64",
    ];
    rpath = "%%ldcbinarypath%%/../lib-aarch64";
};

but the ldd app/src/main/jniLibs/x86_64/libmain.so still gives me the same result, and the problem persists.

This smells like you're compiling against glibc and then trying to deploy to an environment that doesn't use it. To allow a real/proper diagnosis rather than guesswork, though, we'd want a [mre] -- the shortest/simplest possible set of fully self-contained steps we can follow without changes to see the same problem ourselves.

(How are you compiling the library? If you're compiling it using host-native tools linking against the host libc... well, that would explain the problem).

"To allow a real/proper diagnosis rather than guesswork, though, we'd want a minimal reproducible example". Yes, I know. As mentioned, the app is a vulkan app, and currently sits at a little of 4k lines of code. I'm not sure how much of that I can peel back to get an MVP. :(

in terms of compiling, dlang uses dub as a package manager, which I'm using. It looks like it's compiling some c code in the background. if you're compiling it using host-native tools linking against the host libc ... I know all of those words, but not really what you're asking. This smells like you're compiling against glibc ... deploying to an environment that doesn't use it. How would I confirm that?

One place to start might be inspecting ldd libmain.so (if ldd says it successfully links against glibc, that's a smell), though there are probably more targeted ways to inspect for libraries linking against bionic as well; https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/refs/heads/main/android-changes-for-ndk-developers.md describes a bunch of differences one could sniff around for in objdump or such.

@CharlesDuffy ldd libmain.so indicated that I was linking to the glibc. I tried to edit my ldc2.conf file to use alternate libraries, but it didn't work. Added some logs and config to the question.

Interesting. I think there's enough here that the question is solidly answerable now, though it'll need to be someone who knows the D toolchain better than I do to answer it.

While I can't pretend to have special expertise here, if I were in your shoes, while waiting for genuine experts to show up I'd start by tracing the build process to see (1) if the config file is being read, and (2) whether the linker selection &c specified is actually being honored. One could measure those things with strace with a huge performance impact, or with sysdig with a much smaller one (but more work involved in setup, and more permissions needed at runtime).
